# Transaction to Insert errors

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have read lots of questions tried lots of different ways to no success.
I am trying to insert into multiple tables. 
I have a transaction, but it is throwing  the error:

```
  Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query on the  lines
```

starting:

```
  if ($result).
```

I think I am missing something simple. This is really getting to me I must have spent a week trying to sort this out.
My tables are all innodb, all the column data type match.
I can do the individual insertions but not the multiple insertions.

```
 <?php

 $jid = $_REQUEST['JID'];
 $CLx = $_REQUEST['CL'];
 $CL = str_replace("'", "\'", $CLx);
 $ADx = $_REQUEST['AD'];
 $AD = str_replace("'", "\'", $ADx);
 $DT = $_REQUEST['DT'];
 $SS1 = $_REQUEST['SS1'];
 $SS2 = $_REQUEST['SS2'];
 $SS3 = $_REQUEST['SS3'];
 $SVFNx = $_REQUEST['SVFN'];
 $SVFN = str_replace("'", "\'", $SVFNx);
 $CS = $_REQUEST['CS'];
 $OFTC = $_REQUEST['OFTC'];
 $SV = $_REQUEST['SV'];



 $dbConnection = mysqli_connect ('10.169.999.999', 'boiw', 'Tx', 'bw1_pp');

 mysqli_autocommit($dbConnection, false);

 $flag =true;

  $squery1 = "INSERT INTO `awg` (`JID`,`CL`,`AD`,`DT`,`SS1`,`SS2`,`SS3`,`SVFN`,`CS) VALUES ($jid,$CL,$AD,$DT,$SS1,$SS2,$SS3,$SVFN,$CS)";
  $squery2 = "INSERT INTO `cae` (`JID`,`CL`,`AD`,`DT`,`SS1`,`SS2`,`SS3`,`SVFN`) VALUES ($jid,$CL,$AD,$DT,$SS1,$SS2,$SS3,$SVFN)";
  $squery3 = "INSERT INTO `calc` (`JID`,`CL`,`AD`,`DT`,`SS1`,`SS2`,`SS3`,`SVFN`) VALUES ($jid,$CL,$AD,$DT,$SS1,$SS2,$SS3,$SVFN)";
  $squery4 = "INSERT INTO `costings` (`JID`,`CL`,`AD`,`DT`,`SS1`,`SS2`,`SS3`,`SVFN`) VALUES ($jid,$CL,$AD,$DT,$SS1,$SS2,$SS3,$SVFN,$CS)";
  $squery5 = "INSERT INTO `hazzard` (`JID`,`CL`,`AD`,`DT`,`SS1`,`SVFN`,`CS`) VALUES ($jid,$CL,$AD,$DT,$SS1,$SVFN,$CS)";
  $squery6 = "INSERT INTO `spay` (`JID`,`CL`,`AD`,`DT`,`SS1`,`SS2`,`SS3`,`SVFN`,`surveyor`) VALUES ($jid,$CL,$AD,$DT,$SS1,$SS2,$SS3,$SVFN,$SV)";
  $squery7 = "INSERT INTO `spix` (`JID`,`CL`,`AD`,`DT`,`SS1`,`SVFN`,) VALUES ($jid,$CL,$AD,$DT,$SS1,$SVFN)";
  // I have tried stating the values as $X, '$X',....no difference
  $result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query1);

  if (!$result) {
  $flag = false; 
  echo "Error details: " . mysqli_error($dbConnection) . ".";
  }

  $result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query2);

  if (!$result) {
  $flag = false; 
  echo "Error details: " . mysqli_error($dbConnection) . ".";
  }

  $result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query3);  // and so on

  if (!$result) {
  $flag = false; 
  echo "Error details: " . mysqli_error($dbConnection) . ".";
  }

  if ($flag) {
  mysqli_commit($dbConnection);
  echo "All queries were executed successfully";
  } else {
  mysqli_rollback($dbConnection);
  echo "All queries were rolled back";
  }

  mysqli_close($dbConnection);

  ?>
```

Comment: You defined a bunch of `squery*` variables but randomly use undefined `$query*` variables in your `mysqi_query` hence the warning.

Comment: Also, some code-advice: instead of using a bunch of `squery*` variables, just use an array so that you can simply loop and process each query (and not have to repeat the same block of code 7 times). As well, learn about [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: hi Mikey, thanks for the reply. this code is run manually about max 12 times a day where I transfer data between databases.  When you say I defined a bunch of `squery` variables..but use undefined, that's why I put in // etc etc,  any way I will put them back in, so you can see if this is the problem.I am aware of sql injection  and yes I have to learn more about pdo

Comment: @Dai13 read what Mikey wrote, again.  This line: `$result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query1);` **references a variable `$query1` that does not appear anywhere in your code at all,** so the error is quite correct. The closest thing you have is `$squery1` but "close" doesn't count.

Comment: thanks Michael its now working fine.. updates 9 tables at once, thankyou for all your valuable help.